# Any implementation of Map<K1, K2, V>, i.e. two keys?

Tags: java, generics, maps

I need a map that has two keys, e.g.

```
Map2<String /*ssn*/, String /*empId*/, Employee> _employees;
```

So that I can

```
_employees.put(e.ssn(), e.empId(), e)
```

And later

```
_employees.get1(someSsn);
_employees.get2(someImpId);
```

Or even

```
_employees.remove1(someImpId);
```

I am not sure why I want to stop at two, why not more, probably because that's the case I am I need right now :-) But the type needs to handle fixed number of keys to be type-safe -- type parameters cannot be vararg :-)

Appreciate any pointers, or advice on why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Something like Boost::MultiIndex (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), but for Java.

Answer (score 4):

My first thought was: the easiest way to do this, I think, would be two maps.

```
Map< String, Map< String,Employee> > _employees;
```

But from what it looks like, you just want to be able to look up an employee by either SSN or ID.  What's to stop you then from making two maps, or at worst a class that contains two maps?

As a clarification, are you looking for a *compound key* being employees are uniquely identified by the combination of their SSN and ID, but not either one by itself, or are you looking for two different ways of referencing an employee?

Comment: No, it's not a composite key, but two different keys.

Two maps is exactly what I am doing right now. Already in two different classes. When I needed it in a third class, I decided to write a Map2 class, but wanted to check first if one already existed.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine the *main* key would be `empId`, so I would build a `Map` with that as the key, i.e. `empId` ---> `Employee`. All other unique attributes (e.g. `ssn`) would be treated as *secondary* and will use separate `Map`s as a lookup table for `empId` (e.g. `ssn` ---> `empId`).

This implementation makes it easy to add/remove employees, since you only need to change one `Map`, i.e. `empId` ---> `Employee`; the other `Map`s can be rebuilt only when needed.

Comment: Interesting. It allows deletion from any key, even if there any many. It might help me solve the problems I face with @krosenvold approach.

Answer (score 2):

The [Spiffy Framework](http://spiffyframework.sourceforge.net/) appears to provide exactly what you`re looking for. From the Javadocs:

> A two-dimensional hashmap, is a
>   HashMap that enables you to refer to
>   values via two keys rather than one

The relevant class is [TwoDHashMap](http://spiffyframework.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html). It also provides a [ThreeDHashMap](http://spiffyframework.sourceforge.net/javadoc/spiffy/core/util/ThreeDHashMap.html).

Comment: The x-DHashMap seems like a Map with a single but compound x-dimensional key... you can't use each key independently to access the values.