# Dual look up Map

Tags: java, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any implementation of Map<K1, K2, V>, i.e. two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311103/any-implementation-of-mapk1-k2-v-i-e-two-keys)

I need to store name and id as key value pair. However I need to look up by both name and id at times in my program. I don't want to create two HashMap (or double the memory consumption by storing name-id and id-name pair)

What is a suitable data structure for it? Is there a Standard implementation in java for this?

Comment: Are you trying to look up name by id, and also id by name?  So, the lookup is bi-directional?  Not that you have two actual keys, for some third value?

Comment: Its not clear whether you need a bidirectional map or a map with multiple keys.

Comment: Why not use the two HashMaps? Behind the scenes, its not making clones of the objects but instead using the pointers, so there will not be double memory consumption (yes there is some extra memory). Also who says that the data structure that supports it behind the scenes does not use two data structures. I think your concern about memory is invalid. The other point is do you really need to be that concerned about the extra memory it uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use also guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). And to get the inverse map is as simple as:

```
BiMap<Integer, String> biMap = HashBiMap.create();
biMap.put(1, "a");
biMap.put(2, "b");
BiMap<String, Integer> invertedMap = biMap.inverse(); //to get the name,id map
```

The only constraint is that your keys and values should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Commons-Collections has BidiMap that you can use:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Guava has [`HashBiMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) which keeps track of both directions of a mapping for you.  Currently, its implementation basically just maintains a `HashMap` in each direction, but the next release will use a custom data structure saving something like ~38% on memory.

Essentially, `HashBiMap` behaves exactly like a `Map`, except that it rejects duplicate values, and you can get a view of the other direction -- values to keys -- by calling `inverse()`.

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)